# Set $A$ nowhere dense if and only if closure of metric space $X$ less closure of $A$ is $X$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $A\subseteq X$. Then $A$ is nowhere dense $\iff$ $\overline{X\setminus\overline{A}}=X$.

**Proof:** $A$ is nowhere dense $\iff$ for any $x\in \overline{A}$ and $\varepsilon>0$, $B(x,\varepsilon)\setminus \overline{A}\ne \emptyset$ [by definition] $\iff x\in \overline{X\setminus \overline{A}}$ for any $x\in \overline{A}\cup (X\setminus \overline{A})$.

What I don't understand in this proof is how $x$ must be in  $\overline{A}\cup (X\setminus \overline{A})$ and why $\overline{X\setminus \overline{A}}=\overline{A}\cup (X\setminus \overline{A})=X$. Are some topological identities involved here?

Comment: An easier argument: since interior and closure operators are [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)#Interior_operator) one can write (taking $S=\overline{A}$) $$\text{int}\,(\overline{A})=X\setminus(\overline{X\setminus\overline{A}}).$$ Nowhere dense means by definition that the LHS is empty, it is the same as $\overline{X\setminus\overline{A}}=X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$\Longrightarrow$": *Case 1*: If $x\in \overline{A}$. For $\epsilon = 1/n$, get $x_n$ such that $d(x_n,x)<1/n$ and $x_n\notin A$. Since $x_n\to x$, it follows that $x$ belongs to the closure of $X\setminus A$. *Case 2*: If $x\notin A$, then $x\in X\setminus A \subseteq \overline{X\setminus A}$.

"$\Longleftarrow$": Let $x\in\overline{A}$. By hypothesis, $x\in\overline{X\setminus\overline{A}}$. So there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X\setminus \overline{A}$ such that $x_n\to x$. Hence for every $\epsilon > 0$, we find $x_n$ such that $x_n\in B(x,\epsilon)\setminus \overline{A}$.

Answer (score 1):

The way to observe that is to remember that the closure of a set in a metric space is the set of all limit points of the set. So the open ball around $x$ that has a non empty intersection means you can create a sequence that will converge to $x$. You can do this construction to any $x$ in $X$ because $A$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by an open ball that has a non-empty intersection? Namely, a non-empty intersection with what?